# A bug with iOS5 (Safari), a "position:fixed' div, and tall forms

Tags: html, css, ios5, css-position

All,

I'm working on a web application that includes a very "tall" form. (By tall, it mean that it's several hundred percent taller than a typical screen).

The design calls for a "footer" anchored to the bottom of the screen that's ALWAYS visible, regardless of the user's position in the form.

In other words, the footer should be visible regardless of whether the user is near the top, middle, or bottom of the form, and the form should scroll "underneath" it.

To implement this, I've created the footer as a div with `position:fixed`, and `bottom:0`.

This works perfectly on all the browsers I've tested, including Safari on iOS5.

Except there's **ONE** bug...

If the user is near the top of the form, and gives focus to one of the text fields - as expected, iOS shows the keyboard.

Each time the user the clicks **Next** button, iOS "tabs" her to the next field.

As she progresses down the form by repeatedly clicking **Next**, iOS automatically "scrolls up" the form, so her position on the form remains in view.

However, iOS doesn't seem to update the position of the `position:fixed` footer div - it incorrectly scrolls up along with the rest of the form.

If the user dismisses the keyboard, the div is restored to it's "proper" place, so this isn't an unrecoverable error. But, the fact that the footer moves at all is a glaring problem.

Is this a bug or shortcoming with iOS's implemention of `position:fixed`? Or, is there something I'm doing wrong?

Many thanks in advance!

**[UPDATE]**

Remy Sharp (aptly named) has just written an excellent and detailed post about a variety of bugs and issues with `position:fixed` on iOS/Safari: http://remysharp.com/2012/05/24/issues-with-position-fixed-scrolling-on-ios/. It's a must-read if you're thinking about using `position:fixed` on a site intended for iOS users...

Answer (score 2):

I know that `position:fixed` was not originally supported in early versions of iOS, I know iOS5 does support it but I have had issue with it in the past. If your footer is some sort of control bar then I would suggest using a CSS sticky footer then all pages/content could be loaded into a `div` above this.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using jQuery? If so, I suspect something like this work work:

```
$(":input").focus( function() {
  $(window).scrollTop( $(window).scrollTop() + 1 );
});
```

By scrolling the page 1px after focusing a new form element it *should* reset the fixed element's bottom attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the fix, without having  the footer jump around on you.

1. first you wrap the header and body/section in a div. Make that div scrollable.
2. than you position absolute the footer and position relative everything else.
3. add fixed heights.

See it working here, http://yinnetteolivo.com/footerbottom.html

Your welcome :)

Comment: Yinnette, That's a great solution. The problem with it, though (unless I misunderstand), is that it requires me to have a fixed height for the body. This isn't possible on a non-iOS device, where the window can be resized. (Also, rumors are that the iPhones 5 may have a different screen height than prior models, which also means I shouldn't assume a fixed height for the body section.) I realize I can use JavaScript to adjust the body height style on a window resize event, but that gets pretty janky...

Answer (score 0):

None of the other answers I've found for this bug have worked for me. I was able to fix it simply by scrolling the page back up by 34px, the amount mobile safari scrolls it down. with jquery:

```
$('.search-form').on('focusin', function(){
    $(window).scrollTop($(window).scrollTop() + 34);
});
```

This obviously will take effect in all browsers, but it prevents it breaking in iOS.